# Can strenuous or exhaustive exercises in old age weaken muscles like in post-polio syndrome?

Tags: polio

Can strenuous or exhaustive exercises in old age damage motor neurons like in post-polio syndrome?

Those with post-polio syndrome are advised to do moderate but not strenuous or exhaustive exercises. The concern is that it can damage the nerves. The theory is that when motor neurons enlarge too much, they can be overstressed and even killed.
https://www.polioplace.org/living-with-polio/how-exercise-if-you-are-living-post-polio-syndrome

Since aging leads to a loss of motor neurons and the enlargement of the surviving ones to reinnervate the orphaned muscle fibres, wouldn't improper exercises damage the neurons and increase weaknesses like in post-polio syndrome?

Comment: I think you're not considering that people with PPS have lost upwards of 75% of their motor neurons to begin with, so they have nothing to spare. Not so of simply aging.